# Check application is minimized/background

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am so surprised!

Because not able identify application currently in foreground or background,

when i pressed home button and my application is not in foreground. then after i have used to check application running in foreground or not.

```
public boolean isAppOnForeground()
    {

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) { return false; }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses)
        {
            if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) { return true; }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

it will returns always **true** even if my application actually not in foreground.

**Note:**
My application have 2 services,
1 service will be canceled when application is removed from recent task list( **that i have achieved.**)
2 service will be canceled when application goes in background. (that is check wifi signal strength.)

**how to know app is foreground or background?**

**how to stop service when application is not in foreground?**

Comment: i have check 2/3 questions of stackoverflow. but not working at all even if it is already accepted answers.

Comment: i can not use onPause() method because my service is called at every 20 seconds. if i will stop my service on onPause() method and start on  OnResume() method then timer will reset.

Answer (score 3):

Rely on `Activity` callback methods, such as `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onResume()`, that will give you hints on the current state of `Activity`. The [Activity reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) gives a very broad explanation of every of those methods.

Comment: Yeap. There is `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` for such cases http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html

Comment: for that minimum api level 14 needed.

Comment: Also, these callbacks indicate if activity is started, stopped... Not application. If you go from one activity to another, they will be fired too. Not only when application is minimized

Comment: @Zoran, There's no such notion of "application being stopped" or "minimized" in Android. If your Application contains only a ContentProvider, or a BroadcastReceiver - how would you say that your application has been stopped or minimized?

Comment: I know there isn't. I worked on it and hack i used was to check in onPause after some period of time (2,3 seconds) is another activity active. If it is then application is active. If not application is not active. But, this is not so elegant solution and also, not always correct

Comment: In your case, you can implement your second service, which should stop once "the application goes in background", can be implemented as a bound service (just google "bound services"). This type of service lives as long as there are any clients to it, and you can consider every Activity as a client. When there are no clients left it means that the service can stop.

Answer (score 1):

try handling onpause() event of activity class. Onpause is called when activity goes out of focus.

Comment: We don't get callback for chrome tabs . So if you open a link with a chrome tab you'll treat this as a minimize but the app will still be on the foreground.